# Audio DAC for raspberry pi with 2 outputs (build in sspeakers + TS audio out)

Tags: audio, electronics, midi

I'm working on a project for one of my band that runs on a raspberry pi with [samplerbox](https://www.samplerbox.org/). the raspberry pi is connected to a powered speaker and a midi keyboard, and I can play from a set of samples I have on a USB stick.

I want to buy a [PCM2704 based DAC](https://he.aliexpress.com/item/4000753057186.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.752f1a776sD0is&algo_pvid=9d14e3eb-c904-45ac-9321-2eeb44e6594e&aem_p4p_detail=202109090444124156656432564720028140738&algo_exp_id=9d14e3eb-c904-45ac-9321-2eeb44e6594e-4&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2210000007180663108%22%7D) for the raspberry pi for amplification and better sound quality. But I would also love if I could have 2 output options:

- build in speaker so I can hear myself play (with an option to mute)
- a 1/4 inch TS cable line out for connecting to a mixer (probably need to convert stereo to mono)

I'm pretty new to audio on the raspberry pi and I'm a programmer with not much knowledge about electronics.

Any help on how to get an acceptable result would be appreciated :-)

Thanks!